# Increase the connection timeout for web service in glassfish

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish

In our java application we use web services and now it has default timeout. We are using glassfish server.The error message we get is

```
HTTP transport error: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

So is there any option to increase the timeout?

Comment: You can't increase the connect timeout beyond the platform default of a minute or so, which is already plenty. If you're getting these you have a different problem.

Comment: Please check whether host your are trying to reach is available, your proxy settings are passing through etc...